# Validating MySQL queries on php

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to get the query that it's being tried to be executed on PHP?

Here is the code i'm trying:

```
public static function executeInsertQuery($sqlQuery)
{
    $dbTable = mysql_query($sqlQuery, self::$_dbLink);

    if($dbTable === false){
        Models_Error::throwException("Connection to table failed.", 'database');
    }

    return null;
}
```

How can I validate that to be always an Insert into query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on being passed a query.

In my current project, if I want to insert something, it looks like this:

```
DB::insert("tablename",array(
    "column" => "value",
    "col2"   => "val2",
    "foo"    => "bar"
));
```

This is then translated into a proper query (using PDO in this case, but that doesn't matter here)

Comment: thanks! I will try it that way, but anyways I'm interested in the validation process.

Comment: I mean, it's absolutely better defining the functions so, that it's clear the function, but I find really interesting the validation process of large strings